# Shared CMake scripts between multiple projects

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, cmake-modules

I'm looking for a way to share CMake scripts between multiple projects.

In a repo called `somelib` I have a `cmake` folder, and from the other projects I want to include the scripts in it. In the `CMakeLists.txt` of `somelib` I include many files from the `cmake` folder.

My projects declare "somelib" as an external dependency like so :

```
include(FetchContent)                                                                   
FetchContent_Declare(                                                                   
    somelib                                                                              
    GIT_REPOSITORY git@git.somewhere.com:somewhere/somelib.git                             
    GIT_TAG        origin/master                                                        
)                                                                                       
                                                                                        
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(somelib)
```

I'm not sure this is a good practice so feel free to correct me, but I'm willing to include the `CMakeLists.txt` of `somelib` so that my project include all the files that `somelib` includes.

So after the `FetchContent_MakeAvailable` I did :

```
include(${somelib_SOURCE_DIR}/CMakeLists.txt)
```

This include by itself works just fine, but the issue lies in the `CMakeLists.txt` of `somelib`. Indeed, the includes it does are not relative to its location resulting in errors like :

```
CMake Error at _build/_deps/somelib-src/CMakeLists.txt:26 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    cmake/Cache.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:47 (include)


CMake Error at _build/_deps/somelib-src/CMakeLists.txt:29 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    cmake/Linker.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:47 (include)


CMake Error at _build/_deps/somelib-src/CMakeLists.txt:33 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    cmake/CompilerWarnings.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:47 (include)
```

I do realize that instead of including the `CMakeLists.txt` I could simply do :

```
include(${somelib_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Cache.cmake)
include(${somelib_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Linker.cmake)
include(${somelib_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/CompilerWarnings.cmake)
```

But this will become quite big as the time goes by (plus it will be duplicated between all my projects), so I would like to have a single entry point, a single thing I can include to have everything at hand in my CMakeLists. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do `include(${somelib_SOURCE_DIR}/CMakeLists.txt)` since `FetchContent_MakeAvailable(somelib)` already calls `add_subdirectory` on that same file.

If you want access to its scripts, then just run:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${somelib_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
include(Cache)
include(Linker)
include(CompilerWarnings)
```

---

> But this will become quite big as the time goes by (plus it will be duplicated between all my projects), so I would like to have a single entry point, a single thing I can include to have everything at hand in my CMakeLists. Is it possible?

You could also move these helpers to their own repository and have every project FetchContent *that*. Then its CMakeLists.txt would just have this:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}" PARENT_SCOPE)
```

And you would run:

```
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(my_helpers)
include(MyHelpers)
```

where `MyHelpers.cmake` simply `include()`s all the other helpers.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks a lot ;)